# Leveraging WPF binding with non-incremental, full model updates

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to handle this scenario with WPF by leveraging its binding capabilities.
I have a model that I don't control, it's an external system that, given some inputs (lots, actually) produces an output (lots here too). The output of this system is what I need to display on the UI, but I'm wondering how I should leverage WFP bindings to carry out incremental updates, since I don't control the model and can't know what has changed in the output since last call to the external system (actually, very little might have changed, so it really doesn't make sense to rebind the while model).

I would like to be able to perform incremental updates to the UI instead of rebinding the entire data, which kills the smoothness of the UI and represents a usability problem.
Is there a common way of handling this or should I just reflect over the output and produce change notifications artificially?

Answer (score 1):

Store the otuputs in ObservableCollection(s) and bind your UI elements to that. Write code to update/add your model outputs to these ObservableCollection(s) in the background and your elements bound to these ObservableCollection(s) will update automatically.

There is a good article by Ken Getz on how to achive this over on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd252944.aspx)

Comment: I know about the ObservableCollection class, the problem is that my model is not in that form when generated by the external system. So, are you suggesting that I map it to an ObservableCollection and then handle additions and other kind of changes manually by inspecting the model every time and changing the ObservableCollection accordingly? I was hoping for a cleanest solution honestly.

Comment: My suggestion was to convert the data coming out of your model into business objects (CLR classes) and make ObservableCollection(s) of these objects that your UI elements will bind to. As your background process queries your model for any changes it will update/add/delete these business objects from ObservableCollection(s) and your UI elements will pick up the changes through binding...

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. Are there any patterns for handling updates to a bound UI when you cannot leverage incremental model updates?